# Submit a form with post data in while loop in PHP

Tags: php

```
$i = 1;
while ($getPending = $getPendin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
<form action="https://www.dummy.com/abc/dummyurl" method="post" name="payuForm" id="payu<?php echo $i?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="position-absolute" name="msg" value="<?php echo $str; ?>"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<?php echo 'payu'.$i?>').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Submitting the form opening the url and while loop exiting in the first iteration. I want to execute all the forms one by one and update the result in the database by the response.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you look like not need a user interaction within your form, if so,
you can do the request directly on PHP only, using curl for example, like this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

while ($getPending = $getPendin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dummy.com/abc/dummyurl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  // method "post"

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            http_build_query(array('msg' => $str)));    // Your data in the array()

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if ($server_output == "OK") {
        // Here you update the result in the database in response
    } else {
    }
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

---

If you don't want to use the approach above, and would like to use html/js, you can use the ajax approach, like this :

```
<?php while ($getPending = $getPendin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    $.post( 
        "https://www.dummy.com/abc/dummyurl", 
        { msg: <?= $str ?> },   // Your data here
        function(data) {
            // success
            // Here you make a second json request to update the result in the database
            // A php that you have created to add the data into your base
            $.post( 
                "https://your-own-url.com/for-update-data-by-the-result.php", 
                { yourfield1: data.valuefield1 },
                function() {
                    // success, handle it if you nee
                }
            );
        }
    );
    
<?php } ?>
```

---

PS: If you do not need user interaction (for fill a field for example), then the pure php approach is the preferred way

---

These approaches can or are to improve and customize as your need